# What ports do I need to open up on my Win 2k12 server for MSSQL Express 2008?

Tags: windows, firewall, sql-server-2008, port

I'm running Microsoft SQL Express 2008 on a Windows 2012 Server box. Got everything work, and I even manage to connect with the firewall down. But I dont really want the firewall turned off at all times so what port do I need to open up?

I've allready have the two inbound rules with TCP port 1433 and 1434 but I still seem to be missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This Microsoft Support article for Windows 2008 might help you:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968872/en-us

**Update:**

Just noticed that you asked for Windows Server 2012. I am not sure if this is still working.

Comment: In Visual studio, do i specify Server as "IP\InstanceName"? At home with the firewall down it connectable on "SERVER\SQLEXPRESS"

Comment: @Jason94 Sorry, I cannot tell for Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Browser uses *UDP* port 1434, not TCP. If you're connecting using an instance ID, you need UDP 1434 open for the SQL browser service.

Alternatively, you can reinstall SQL Express and make sure that it's the default instance, then you'll only need port 1433 open.